# Proof that conditional expectation mapping is self-adjoint

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

In our textbook it is stated that

$$E[X \cdot E[Y|Z]] = E[Y \cdot E[X|Z]]$$

The wikipedia page for conditional expectation states it also can be shown that the expressions above are equal to $E[E[X|Z] \cdot E[Y|Z]]$.

Intuitively, I can understand why this is true, but how can I formally prove that the three expressions are equal?

My work:

$$E[X \cdot E[Y|Z]]$$
$$ = E[E[X \cdot E[Y|Z] | Z]]$$
$$ = E[E[X|Z] \cdot E[Y|Z]]$$

Similarly, we can show that $E[Y \cdot E[X|Z]] = E[E[X|Z] \cdot E[Y|Z]]$.

But I'm not sure whether the derivation is correct.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.